# Difference over sums in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a table like the following:

```
PARENTREF    TRANSTYPE(BIT(1))    DUEDATE(DateTime)    TOTAL
     2038                    0           2015-01-01     1000
     2038                    1           2015-03-05      500
     2039                    0           2015-01-01     1000
     2040                    0           2015-01-01     1000
     2041                    0           2015-01-01     1000
     2040                    1           2015-04-07      200
```

I want a `SELECT` query that returns `SUM(TOTAL)` when `TRANSTYPE=1` subtracted from `SUM(TOTAL)` when `TRANSTYPE=0` for each distinct `PARENTREF`. I also would like to get in a separate column the `DUEDATE` for the `PARENTREF` when `TRANSTYPE=0`. There may be only one `PARENTREF` with `TRANSTYPE=0` so that won't be a problem. In other words, I should get the following table:

```
PARENTREF    DUEDATE(DateTime)    TOTAL
     2038          2015-01-01       500
     2039          2015-01-01      1000
     2040          2015-01-01       800
     2041          2015-01-01      1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(1-transtype*2)` is `1` when `transtype=0` and is `-1` when `transtype=1`, so query subtract values of `total` where `transtype=1` from value of `total` where `transtype=0`. `max` ignore `null` values, so it select only not `null` value where `transtype=0`.

```
select
    parentref,
    sum((1-transtype*2)*total) as total,
    max(if(transtype=0,duedate,null)) as duedate
from tablename
group by parentref
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
select t.PARENTREF,t.DueDate,(t.Total-isnull(m.Total,0)) as total 

   from tabl t LEFT outer join tabl m on t.PARENTREF=m.PARENTREF and t.TRANSTYPE <> m.TRANSTYPE

   where (t.Transtype=0 ) and (isnull(m.Transtype,1)=1 )
```

Please Check out this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4988/1

or use thiss...

```
  select t.PARENTREF,t.DueDate,(sum(t.Total)-sum(isnull(m.Total,0))) as total 
   from tabl t LEFT outer join tabl m on t.PARENTREF=m.PARENTREF and t.TRANSTYPE <> m.TRANSTYPE
   where (t.Transtype=0 ) and (isnull(m.Transtype,1)=1 )
   group by t.PARENTREF,t.DueDate
```

Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4988/2